# How to capture anctions window:beforeunload Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, window

I have a problem with window event beforeunload in Angular app.
i wants to check if the user navigate to another page, if so i want to clean sessionStorage. I use.

```
   onBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
       event.returnValue = '';
   }
```

Beforeunload event also workd as a page refresh. How to check if the user leaves the application and clear the sesion storage after confirm dialog.

Comment: session storage means it will be auto cleared if he leaves your application means closing a tab or redirected to another website etc

Comment: If i use back navigate browser buttons, i have previous session :( and it is all my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code in constructor of your component class.

**Option 1**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
   exampleService.logout();
});
```

**Option 2**

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
     beforeUnloadHandler(event: any) {
     event.preventDefault();
     // any other code / dialog logic
 }
```

> To distinguish from 2 cases, you should check out this stackoverflow question or related questions, here's one:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412931/how-to-check-if-user-is-refreshing-the-page-or-navigating-to-other-page)

Hope, this helps.

Comment: but I don't want to end the user session if you refresh the application and only if it goes to another page. How to distinguish actions

Comment: You know why performance.navigation.type return type reload if i navigate to another page :(

Comment: @Cylo check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162300/how-can-i-detect-when-the-user-is-leaving-my-site-not-just-going-to-a-different

Comment: I opened link  _blank. I need cheek if user write url in url bar or use tabs. Thanks for help

Comment: I dont resolve my problem. performence.navigation.type return type reload all time :( your link no fix my issue.

Comment: Okay, you can put a confirmation dialog in onbeforeunload event

Comment: I can't. If I use beforeunload and method event.preventDefault(), browser return me confirm dialog, i cant customize and I don't know what the user clicked in the dialog.

Comment: @Cylo can you check on `canDeactivateGuard` concept in angular. That is for the purpose you are talking about.

Comment: whether the router detects external navigation?

Comment: Yes that. @Cylo

Comment: Angular router does not detect the transition to another page, but only navigations inside the app. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will make browser to ask user that whether he wants to lose the unsaved changes or not.

Also, I'm checking whether the form is dirty or not.

If the form is not dirty, browser won't bother the user and close it.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { DetailedUser } from 'src/app/models/detailed-user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-edit',
  templateUrl: './member-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-edit.component.css']
})
export class MemberEditComponent {
  user: DetailedUser = new DetailedUser();
  @ViewChild('userForm') userForm: NgForm;
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  WindowBeforeUnoad($event: any) {

    if (this.userForm.dirty) {
      $event.returnValue = 'Your data will be lost!';
    }
  }
  saveChanges(){
    ....
    this.userForm.reset(this.user);
  }
}
```

the following is the html section

```
     <form (ngSubmit)="saveChanges()" #userForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="introduction">Introduction</label>
          <textarea
            name="introduction"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="user.introduction"
            rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lookingFor">Looking For</label>
          <textarea
            name="lookingFor"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="user.lookingFor"
            rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
```