# Update DB table on browser close in angular 8 appliation

Tags: angular

Have an angular 8 application and I have a scenario where users enters or leaves a specific page A, DB table is updated. But when the user close the browser from Page A, how to update the DB table?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944173/how-to-capture-anctions-windowbeforeunload-angular-8

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to determine the browser window is closing so i can perform an update action on DB table

Comment: Did you read the question in the link I wrote up here ?